# Spectral sequence associated with a Postnikov tower (Solved by myself)

Tags: spectral-sequences, stable-homotopy-category

Suppose $E$ is an $S^1$-spectra of simplicial Nisnevich sheaves. For any $r\in\mathbb{Z}$, we have a distinguished triangle
$$E_{\geq r+1}\longrightarrow E_{\geq r}\longrightarrow F_r\longrightarrow E_{\geq r+1}[1]$$
in $SH_s^{S^1}(k)$, where $_{\geq r}$ denotes the truncation functor (homological index, which is $_{\leq -r}$ in term of cohomological index). We have $F_r\cong H(\pi_r(E))[r]$.

Let $U\in Sm/k$,
$$D_{p,q}^1=[\Sigma^{\infty}U_+[p+q],E_{\geq -p}], E_{p,q}^1=[\Sigma^{\infty}U_+[p+q],F_{-p}].$$ We know that
$$E_{p,q}^1=H^{-q-2p}(U,\pi_{-p}(E)).$$
What does this spectral sequence converge to and what are the $E_{p,q}^2$ terms?

Comment: You should add your answer as an answer, not as part of your question. I can do this for you, if you don't object. But you should add details if you do, certainly more than what you already have.

Comment: @Praphulla Koushik I'm sorry. The question was asked serveral days ago and I had been working on this.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding.. I did not see the history of the question.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The convergence of this spectral sequence is because the Nisnevich topology of schemes has a cohomological dimension. The corresponding filtration is given by
$$F^pH_n=Im([\Sigma^{\infty}U_+[n],E_{\geq -p}]\longrightarrow [\Sigma^{\infty}U_+[n],E])$$. cf. https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/4702/f5e28ad71b82c67e0bb9405cd3e2a1931e5f.pdf

To identify the $E_{p,q}^1$, one could prove that
$$[\Sigma^{\infty}U_+,F[n]]\cong H^n(U,\pi_0(F))$$
for $F\in SH^{S^1}_s(k)^{\heartsuit}$ by using the $\delta$-functor theories. The case for $n=0$ follows from the $t$-structure. For the effaceability, one could show that $H(A)$ is stably fibrant when $A$ is an injective Nisnevich abelian sheaf. For this, one shows that $K(A,n)=\Gamma(A[-n])$ is Brown Gersten fibrant and then it's easy to prove $H(A)$ is an $\Omega$-spectrum. cf. J. F. Jardine, 'Generalized Etale Cohomology Theories'.